# Does SP needs to know SingleSignOnService location in IDP initiated saml SSO?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I am working with a client who is IDP and our application is SP.
The client has not provided SingleSignOnService location. Is it necessary for SP to know the location or SSO can work without that?

Answer (score 4):

With a SAML 2.0 Unsolicited Web SSO event, there is no AuthnRequest generated by your SP, therefore you do not need the SSO endpoint of the IDP.